# help with my wordpress website

Tags: plugins, errors

I cannot get into my website. I was downloading a plugin for simple tags and now every time i try to log or look at my website i get:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function register_importer() in
>   /home/sjdenny/public_html/wp-content/plugins/simple-tagging-import/stp.php
>   on line 198

PLEASE HELP I'm not sure what to do since i cant even log in or look at my site!!!

THANKS

Answer (score 3):

Try disabling the plugin. 
Access the site via FTP, and go to wp-content/plugins and then remove the folder containing the plugin mentioned.